# Zend navigation breadcrumbs

Tags: xml, zend-framework, breadcrumbs, zend-navigation

I have an xml navigation system with article as an element. The breadcrumb works as far as my article page where i display the list of articles with their title (as a link) and a teaser paragraph. The page where i display the full article does not show any breadcrumb navigation.

I know i'm doing something wrong but since i am new to zend i can't figure out where.

I would be grateful if someone could point me towards the right direction.

The XML Navigation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configdata>
  <nav>
    <home>
        <label>Home</label>
        <controller>index</controller>
        <action>index</action>
        <pages>

            <about>
                <label>About</label>
                <controller>index</controller>
                <action>about</action>

            </about>
        <board>
            <label>Executive Committee</label>
            <controller>index</controller>
            <action>committee</action>
        </board>
        <events>
                <label>Events</label>
                <controller>index</controller>
                <action>events</action>
        </events>


        <member>
                <label>CNFS Members</label>
                <controller>index</controller>
                <action>member</action>

            </member>
            <news>
                <label>Blog</label>
                <controller>blog</controller>
                <action>index</action>

            </news>
            <contact>
                <label>Contact</label>
                <controller>index</controller>
                <action>contact</action>
        </contact>
        </pages>
    </home>
</nav>
</configdata>
```

This is the function in the bootstrap file for navigation.

```
<?php
   protected function _initViewNavigation(){
     $this->bootstrap('layout');
     $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
     $view = $layout->getView();
     $config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/navigation.xml','nav');
     $navigation = new Zend_Navigation($config);
     $view->navigation($navigation);
    }
    ?>
```

This is how i display the breadcrumbs in the view:

```
    <?php echo  'Your are here: ' . $this->navigation()->breadcrumbs() ->setMinDepth(0)->setLinkLast(false)->setSeparator("   /  ");?>
```

Comment: Could you join the code of your xml navigation definition, and the ZF version you are using ?

Comment: Hi Frederik. I've added the xml file for your reference. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: What is the url of the page with the full article? also the url of the list of articles with their title? Maybe you are not including the "full article" page in the nav

Comment: Thanks for your comment but frederik solution below works!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your xml, i guess that your articles list is at /blog, and an single article at /blog/article/'articleId' or something similar.

Your "news" section in your navigation map defines an action, "index" but to display an article you use an other action, that's why this node isn't matched anymore.

I guess you would like the current article's title to show at the end of your breadcrumb, and to do that you must append a custom page as a child of the "news" node, and setting it as 'active' :

```
public function articleAction(){
    //get your article
    $article = ....


    $page = new Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc(array(  
            'label'         => $article->getTitle(),  
            'controller'    => 'blog',  
            'action'        => 'article',  
            'params'        => array(
                'id' => $article->getId() // replace with the param name + value that you actually use in your url
                 )
            )
       );
    $page->setActive(true);

    $this->view->_helper->navigation()->getContainer()->findOneBy('controller','blog')->addPage($page);
```

I wrote this code by memory without testing, so if it doesn't work as expected just tell me, i'll test and update this answer

Comment: Thank you Frederik. I can now see the article title in the breadcrumb navigation but the article title also appears below the main navigation (below blog as a sub nav).

Is there anyway to just display the article title in the breadcrumb but not in the main navigation?

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: you have to set the maxDepth of your main menu, by appending `->setMaxDepth($depth)` to your helper invocation. try with a depth of 0 or 1